# Convert rownum from Oracle in Postgres, in "having" clause

Tags: oracle, postgresql, group-by, having, rownum

I need to convert a query from Oracle SQL to Postgres.

```
select count(*) from  table1 group by column1 having max(rownum) = 4
```

If I replace "rownum" with "row_number() over()", I have an error message: "window functions are not allowed in HAVING". 
Could you help me to get the same result in Postgres, as in Oracle?

Comment: To be honest: I don't think this query makes a lot of sense in Oracle. What exactly is that supposed to do?

Comment: I tested for a concrete table. The table has 6 rows, and the column from group-by clause has values: 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1. For max(rownum) = 5, returns 4, for max(rownum) = 6 returns 2, and for another value, the query does not return any row.

Comment: can you update your question to include the table definition and the insert statements, please?

Comment: insert into pac_payment_modes (mode_id, open_default) values ('CC', 0);
insert into pac_payment_modes (mode_id, open_default) values ('AB', 0);
insert into pac_payment_modes (mode_id, open_default) values ('ABBUONO', 0);
insert into pac_payment_modes (mode_id, open_default) values ('BANK', 1)
insert into pac_payment_modes (mode_id, open_default) values ('BONIF', 0);
insert into pac_payment_modes (mode_id, open_default) values ('CT', 1)    ; The table is pac_payment_modes , open_default - column from group-by, mode_id - PK

Comment: please edit your question to include this information. And please provide the create table statement (ie. `create table pac_payment_modes (....);`) so that we can replicate your table exactly.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "PAC_PAYMENT_MODES" 
   ( "MODE_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
 "OPEN_DEFAULT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0, 
   )  ;
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PAC_PAYMENT_MODES_PK" ON "PAC_PAYMENT_MODES" ("MODE_ID") 
  ALTER TABLE "PAC_PAYMENT_MODES" ADD CONSTRAINT "PAC_PAYMENT_MODES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MODE_ID")
  ALTER TABLE "PAC_PAYMENT_MODES" MODIFY ("MODE_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);   The other columns are not important for this case.

Comment: And syntax for creating table in PostgreSQL:  CREATE TABLE pac_payment_modes
(
  mode_id character varying(16) NOT NULL,
  open_default numeric DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT pac_payment_modes_pk PRIMARY KEY (mode_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);   The values are the same in both databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will do what your Oracle query is doing.

```
select count(*) from 
(select column1, row_number() over () as x from table1) as t 
group by column1 having max(t.x) = 6;
```

**However**

Neither oracle not postgres will guarantee the order in which records are read unless you specify an order by clause.  So running the query multiple times is going to be inconsistent depending on how the database decides to process the query.  Certainly in postgres any updates will change the underlying row order.

In the example below I've got an extra column of `seq` which is used to provide a consistent sort.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (column1 int, seq int);
insert into table1 values (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,4),(0,5),(1,6);
```

And a revised query which forces the order to be consistent:

```
select count(*) from 
(select column1, row_number() over (order by seq) as x from table1) as t 
group by column1 having max(t.x) = 6;
```

Comment: With first query, offsets 4 and 5 are OK, but offsets 0 to 3 are not OK (they have value 2 or 4, and in Oracle, there are no results for max(rownum) between 1 and 4)

Comment: It works. Thanks! Now I'll adapt this for a bigger query.